# save data with custom keys firebase react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

databaseReference:

[image: example of problem]

Im trying to save data to my firebase realtime database and I need my key to be the users ID and not the random generated unique key I tried child but still got some random keys any help? this is the method I currently have

```
async componentWillMount() {


const {data} = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
  fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
});

this.setState({dataSource: data.map(contact => ({...contact, key: contact.number}))});

const contacts = data.filter(d => d.phoneNumbers);

contactsToUpload.forEach(contact => {
  const number = contact.phoneNumbers[0].number.replace(/\D/g, '');
  const ref = firebase.database().ref('/Contacts/' + number);
  try {
    ref.push(contact.name);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
}
//Currently have
"Contacts" : {
  "5554787672" : {
    "-LWIlxwIETK5UR3O5GkR" : "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
    "-LWImsOurEVDOE-KrkVw" : "Daniel From School"
 }
//Needed
"Contacts" : {
 "5554787672" : {
  "UserId1" : "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
  "UserId2" : "Daniel From School"
 }
```

Comment: How is `contactsToUpload` populated/initialized? Note that it's easiest to help if the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you share is standalone, so has no external dependencies beyond what you shared.

Comment: contactsToUpload is in componentWillMount on the HomeScreen and the variable contact is just the phone numbers from the device I have added the dependencies

Comment: I think it's just `const ref = firebase.database().ref('/Contacts/' + number);
  try {
    ref.set(contact.name);` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `push()` Firebase generates a reference to a new, unique location in the database. So `ref.push()` creates a new, unique location under `ref`.

If you want to simply set the name under the contact's ID, change `ref.push(contact.name);` to:

```
ref.set(contact.name);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. 
Multiple users might upload the same number under different names I would like to keep as a key the user ID and as the value what that user names him I think set will delete the previous key as in I wont be able to keep the different names user have given to that number

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you show two calls that you'd like to run? And then also add the JSON (as text) that you want after those two calls?

Comment: every new user will have the app run the method given above on the first use to add their contacts to the database, 
After two user that both have the same number on the phone the database will have "Contacts" : {
    "5554787672" : {
      "-LWIlxwIETK5UR3O5GkR" : "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
      "-LWImsOurEVDOE-KrkVw" : "Daniel From School"
    }
My ideal scenario is that I can attribute what user uploaded what by having the following 
"Contacts" : {
    "5554787672" : {
      "UserID1" : "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
      "UserID2" : "Daniel From School"
    }
Thanks again for the help

Comment: Have :
"Contacts" : {
    "5554787672" : {
      "-LWIlxwIETK5UR3O5GkR" : "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
      "-LWImsOurEVDOE-KrkVw" : "Daniel From School"
    }
Need: 
"Contacts" : {
    "5554787672" : {
      "UserID1" : "Daniel Higgins Jr.",
      "UserID2" : "Daniel From School"
    }

Comment: Please add the information to your question and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make it readable. Code and data in comments are notoriously hard to read.

Comment: Of course apologies, done. As you can see this is what I currently have from a scenario of two users using the app provided that they have the same phone number on their phone but not the same name for that number. (JSON is added in question). This method Is invoked on every new user to get their contact  form their phones

Answer (score 1):

```
db.ref('UsersList/').child('name you want to use').set({
    email:this.state.email,
    fname: this.state.lastname,
    lname: this.state.firstname,
}).then((data)=>{
    //success callback
    alert('success'+data);
}).catch((error)=>{
    //error callback
    alert('failed'+error);
  })
```

something like this worked for me and I was able to store based on special usernames I needed.

Comment: the .child in the first line will help set a child key under the UserList